# How to remove a text followed by backslash in file using sed or regex pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am having the below contents in a file, I have to remove the text "monitoring" along with the backslash at suffix (`monitoring/`)

```
 <base  href="/monitoring/" />
```

so the output will be like below

```
<base  href="/" />
```

can i achieve this through sed or any other way

Comment: Welcome to the site. In your title you speak about a backslash `\ `, but I only see slashes `/` in the example text. Also, if you are editing HTML or XML files, I would advise using a dedicated parser such as `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Also, please indicate how to identify the line you want to modify. Is it the only tag called `base`? You may also want to edit your post to include what you already tried, so that contributors don't suggest solutions you already know won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would strongly recommend using a dedicated parser such as `xmlstarlet` for structured text, the following `sed` command will work, provided that there is only one such `base` tag in your file:

```
sed -E '/\<base/s,(href="/)[^"]+,\1,' input.html
```

This will act on lines which contain the `<base` pattern, and replace the pattern `href="/any text up to the double quote` with `href="/`, thereby eliminating the text behind the `/`.

Note that this will not edit the file by default. To edit the file, either redirect the output to a file, or use the in-place editing option `i`:

```
sed -i -E '/\<base/s,(href="/)[^"]+,\1,' input.html
```

Comment: thanks for the command, but it just shows the output but the exact file did not get changed. Is there any way to have the changed file

Comment: @Ramanichandran see edited answer

Comment: Thank you @AdminBee

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the document is a properly formatted XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <base href="/monitoring/"/>
</root>
```

The following uses `xmlstarlet` to remove the string `monitoring/` (and everything after it) from any `base` node's `href` attribute that contain that string:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//base/@href[contains(.,"monitoring/")]' \
    -x 'substring-before(.,"monitoring/")' file.xml
```

This outputs an XML document that you should redirect to a new name, and then replace the original file with.